# I would like to install Ubuntu on my home computer

Tags: boot

I need help installing Ubuntu on my home computer i have a mac laptop and a wireless mouse i love to game and i thought Ubuntu would be the best OS for me!

Answer (score 0):

Most people will skip your question because they do not want to be hooked into being a trouble shooter for this type of question, I don't want to be either, but because I want more Linux users out there I will give you advice on what to look for, and you can make your own decision after that.

First off let me say that Linux is just recently making some in roads in the gaming world, but it is not all there yet.  From what I have read you will need to look at Steam for the gaming platform, so before you decide to load Linux on your machine you should go to their website and see if the games you might want to play are available for Linux.  Here is a link to a list:

```
http://store.steampowered.com/search/?term=&sort_by=_ASC&os=linux&page=1
```

If you decide that is what you want to do, I would first try running Linux as a VM, you can download and install VirtualBox on your Mac, and build a VM of Linux on that so you can test it out without overwriting your current OS. Here is a link to VirtualBox, as well as instructions on how to create the VM:

```
https://www.virtualbox.org/

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html
```

You will need to download an Ubuntu ISO from here:

```
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop
```

If you decide that you want to install Linux, then you can burn the ISO to a disk, or USB drive and follow the instructions after that, here is a link to how to do the burning:

```
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto
```

Good luck
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu may not always provide the same level of user friendliness that you have become used to in OSX, but it can be a very good operating system if you decide to switch to it for the right reasons.

There are actually multiple versions of ubuntu, each of which may differ slightly in their user environment, and sometimes in their level of resource demand (which may be important if you are trying to run the OS on an older system). Based on your reason for wanting to switch to Ubuntu, I would suggest looking  around with a google search at some of these options

Ubuntu is a linux based operating system, and it may be helpful to know that there are also many other freely available linux distributions out there which each differ in their user interface and in some other nuances. You might want to look around at these as well

As far as gaming goes, there are some opportunities for gaming on a Ubuntu based system, but this would depend largely on what type of gaming you are looking to get into and what the age and hardware specs of your laptop are.

As is often indicated in popular game clients such as steam, modern games must be programed to operate within the architecture provided by the operating system (linux, unix, windows) and therefore not all games that are released are playable on the ubuntu platform. With that being said, there are still many that are and if you download the steam client, you will be able to view whether or not any game is playable on ubuntu. Additionally, Ubuntu has some good emulators if you are looking to go in that direction. It is also of important note that even if a game (emulated or modern) is playable on the ubuntu system, you will have to make sure that your hardware is capable of handling the game as well. In order to play the game, both your hardware and the Ubuntu environment must be compatible with the game. Often times, game clients such as steam can also give you a good idea of what kind of system specs you need to run a game.

When it comes to installing ubuntu, I generally find that the best method is to create a bootable USB and to install from that. If you still have OSX installed on your mac, you may find it useful to download a program called UNetBootin that will help you in creating a bootable USB. If you select which version of linux you would like to use and download it separately, you can use the UNetBootin tool to format the USB so that you can install from it.

Please note that creating a bootable USB through this method will format and remove all data from your USB. Also note that depending upon how you choose to install linux, you may overwrite your existing OSX installation and may therefore no longer have OSX as an OS on your machine.

All of this being said, Ubuntu, and I think all forms of linux, can be an excellent platform for learning. There are so many different options out there for linux, and linux distributions tend to be so community based that you can really go as deep into working with and manipulating the OS as you want, which is pretty cool.

Good luck in your search on this!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments about Ubuntu and gaming- Is it just gaming you want to do? If you like really old retro 1980's style you could install [Dosbox] and use abandonware. http://www.abandonia.com/

But you can create your USB boot on this site:

[Unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/)

**(I don't think you can't simply boot from a ISO CD with a Mac....)**

Your install depends what you want - and what you want to do. I would not install Ubuntu 16.04LTS as I don't think all the wrinkles have been sorted out yet; I would go for the previous LTS but there are plenty here that would disagree with me.

With the USB option you can try before you install;

List of available distros on the site

Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu, Debian, openSUSE, Arch Linux, Damn Small Linux, SliTaz, Linux Mint, Zenwalk, Slax, Dreamlinux, Elive, CentOS, Mandriva, FreeBSD, NetBSD, Fedora, PCLinuxOS, Sabayon Linux, Gentoo, MEPIS, LinuxConsole, Frugalware Linux, xPUD, Puppy Linux